# Entity Framework validation warning even though precision is specified: XAF Log

Tags: entity-framework-core, xaf

I have the following in my business object

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

and

```
   [ModelDefault("DisplayFormat", "{0:g}")]
   [ModelDefault("EditMask", "g")]
   [DataType("decimal(18,5)")]
   public decimal Score { get; set; }
```

The application runs as expected but in eXpressAppFramework.log I see

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation: Warning: No type was
> specified for the decimal property 'Score' on entity type
> 'RatingEntry'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they
> do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the
> SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values in
> 'OnModelCreating' using 'HasColumnType()', specify precision and scale
> using 'HasPrecision()' or configure a value converter using
> 'HasConversion()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF just doesn't read the DataTypeAttribute as part of its configuration.  Use the ColumnAttribute, eg

```
 [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,5)")]
```

to configure [Column Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-data-types).  The confusion arises because System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is used for more than just EF entity annotations.